# python.exe No entry point error while importing tflearn

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, tflearn

I'm trying to use tflean with tensorflow-gpu 1.13.1 and I get this error

[Picture of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SvHmr.png)
I have tensorflow-cpu and tflearn on my laptop and I dont get this error. Does anyone know what I can do?

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure that this is a problem with your Python and system but not with tflearn and tensorflow gpu 1.13.1. This [link](https://www.thewindowsclub.com/procedure-entry-point-could-not-be-located-in-the-dynamic-link-library) might help you solve the issue. Take a look at these videos as well which will help you solve this issue. [[1]](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dYegqqGxW14) and [[2]](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lWgp6c67ilw)